# How to get current selected data in datalist from gridview inside it?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datalist

i have a datalist and inside it there is many rows and in one of these rows i have a gridview,. i can say that it's like  the following

```
<DataList>
  <tr>
      <td> [textbox1 control]  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td> [textbox2 control]  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 
       <gridview/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</DataList>
```

my problem is when i'm in gridview RowCommand handler i want to get the data that exist in [textbox1 control] and [textbox1 control]

i do the following

```
DataListItem dataListItem = (DataListItem)((GridView)sender).Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent;
string txt = ((TextBox)dataListItem.FindControl([textbox1 control])).Text.Trim();
```

but is this the only way to  ?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

```
string txt = ((TextBox)DataList.Items[0].FindControl([textbox1 control])).Text.Trim();
```

Comment: this could will work if current item is 0 but if is another one ... how can i know ?

Answer (score 0):

> DataListItem dataListItem =
>   (DataListItem)((GridView)sender).Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent; string
>   txt = ((TextBox)dataListItem.FindControl([textbox1
>   control])).Text.Trim(); 
>   but is this the only way to ?

Yes you can replace it by below, supposing that i have a hidden field inside the data list

DataListItem activitiesItem = (DataListItem)((GridView)sender).NamingContainer;

HiddenField hdnActivityID = (HiddenField)activitiesItem.FindControl("hdnActivityID");